# sending arguments to the program class

Tags: c#

i have a function class that  hold all the function. and i want to pass arguments between the functions but not in recursive .

lets say my first function return an array, and i want to send that array to another function that check it.

how can i do it in the Program  class?

i try:

```
  public List InsertFibo()
    {                  
        List<int> Fibo = new List<int>();              
        Console.WriteLine("enter you number");
        string n = Console.ReadLine();
        int numbers = Convert.ToInt32(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("insert numbers");
            string z = Console.ReadLine();
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(z);
            Fibo.Add(number);
        }
        return Fibo; ;

    }

    public bool check(List<int> f)
    {
        int temp1=0;
        int temp2=1;
        int temp3=2;

        if (f[temp1]+f[temp2]==f[temp3])
        {
            temp1++;
            temp2++;
            temp3++;
            return true ;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;   
        }
    }
```

program class

```
Fibonachi f = new Fibonachi();
       Console.WriteLine(f.InsertFibo());
       Console.WriteLine(f.check());
```

how do i do it?

Comment: The code you have here does not make sense with what you have posted. Please consider posting your code for the two functions

Comment: does your method InsertArray return any array ? put some code for both the function. As far as passing an array to a method is concerned you can simply do `void check(Array parameterArray) {...}`

Comment: your question is not clear, please provide more explanation...

Comment: The `Array` class doesn't implement an `InsertArray` method so your question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
Fibonachi f = new Fibonachi();
List list = new List();
list = f.InsertFibo();
Console.WriteLine(list);
Console.WriteLine(f.check(list));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Array a = new Array ();
var b = a.InsertArray()
Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.WriteLine(a.check(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding about your program is that, the function InsertFibo() ask user to enter a number n (say 5) and then enter  n numbers (5 numbers). Then the second function check() is called so as to confirm that the entered numbers form a fibonacci series.

So the call to first function should be something like this

```
Fibonacci Fibonacci = new Fibonacci();
List<int> lstFibNumbers = Fibonacci.InsertFibo();
for(int index = 0; index < lstFibNumbers.Count; index++)
  Console.WriteLine(lstFibNumbers[index]);
```

Now call the check method as

```
Console.WriteLine(Fibonacci.check(lstFibNumbers));
```

The check method will look like this

```
public bool check(List<int> f)
{
  int temp1=0;
  int temp2=1;
  int temp3=2;

  bool IsAFibonacciSeries = false;

  while(temp1 < f.Count)
  {
    if (f[temp1]+f[temp2]==f[temp3])
    {
      temp1++;
      temp2++;
      temp3++;
      IsAFibonacciSeries = true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false; //If anytime the series is not followed, just return false
    }
  }
  return IsAFibonacciSeries;
}
```